# Gnome 3.18 on Fedora 23: LibreOffice ugly appareance when change GTK theme

Tags: gnome, theme, libreoffice

When i change the GTK theme (Gnome 3.18, Fedora 23) the LibreOffice appareance is completely changed, it's looks like the theme was removed.

This is how LO looks with the Arc theme:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Does your operating system offer something like `libreoffice-gtk3`? It's a package that is required for LibreOffice to use gtk3 properly (on Ubuntu). If your LibreOffice isn't using gtk3, you may need to install `libreoffice-gtk2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libreoffice less than version 5.0 only supports GTK2 and even >= version 5.0 only partially supports GTK3, so you need to either:

1. run libreoffice < 5.0 and use a gnome theme that supports both GTK2 and GTK3

or

2. put up with some ugliness in libreoffice 5.0+ due to incomplete support for GTK3.  Some GTK3 themes are worse than others with LO 5.0+
   depending on what GTK3 features they use.  Plain/simple ones are likely to work best.  Eventually GTK3 support will be completed and it will work as expected - there is no way of knowing how long that will take.

Work is progressing on GTK3 support for libreoffice, but it's not finished yet.  See this Feb 2016 blog post by the main libreoffice dev working on GTK3 support: http://caolanm.blogspot.com/2016/02/gtk3-and-libreoffice.html - browse around his blog, he has more posts on the topic.

Phoronix forum has had several articles tracking the GTK3 work on LibreOffice.  Here's a good starting point if you want to read about it:  http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LibreOffice-GTK3-Slides

Comment: odd.  the readme.md on https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme says that it supports both gtk2 and gtk3.  Do you have the `gtk-murrine-engine` package installed on your Fedora system?  there's also a related issue at https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/426

Comment: Yep, i have that package. I think need wait until LO developers fix this. Thank you for your time.